# Html css zooming changes the sizes by few pixels

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In this HTML page 
http://www2.outofscopes.com/biz/index.html

I need to make the title in the same width and vertical location as the gallery.

But when zooming in and out(in chrome) the title overflows, or the images overflow or even go down a line. That happens because of a few pixels changing.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Give it a fixed width? of 960px for example